# JVM crashed always with Memcached IO over

Tags: crash, jvm, tomcat7, spymemcached

OS: CentOS release centos6.x86_64 
spymemcache: spymemcached-2.8.12.jar
App server: Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.47
jdk:  openjdk 1.7.0

### ISSUE

I just upgraded from tomcat 6.0.29 to 7.0.47.

Tomcat has crashed a few times with the report below.

I couldn't find any other references anywhere with this issue.

### Error Report

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdff1e78c25, pid=26931, tid=140597035554560
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0) (build 1.7.0-internal-weipinghe_2013_02_01_12_29-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b30 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0xfc25]  _tr_stored_block+0x115
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid26931.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseCompressedStrings; support was removed in 7.0
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 461 ms
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/q/www/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
2014-08-13 22:55:10.026 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=host/192.168.233.23:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2014-08-13 22:55:10.028 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=host/192.168.252.170:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2014-08-13 22:55:10.028 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=host/192.168.252.171:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2014-08-13 22:55:10.028 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=host/192.168.252.172:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2014-08-13 22:55:10.044 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@2ad8df74
2014-08-13 22:55:10.053 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Could not redistribute to another node, retrying primary node for site_map_refresh_key_111293.
2014-08-13 22:55:10.059 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@285be482
2014-08-13 22:55:10.064 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@7a429b29
2014-08-13 22:55:10.066 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@28f72781
Aug 13, 2014 10:55:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]


===================more information======================

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdff1e78c25, pid=26931, tid=140597035554560
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0) (build 1.7.0-internal-weipinghe_2013_02_01_12_29-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b30 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0xfc25]  _tr_stored_block+0x115
#

# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: 1. Give us full `hs_err.log`
2. Try `-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true` command-line flag

Comment: The blog contains full hs_err.log information.
http://blog.csdn.net/ouyangheshun/article/details/38560867

Comment: This command-line flag(-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true) is not effect. JVM crashs again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028216

Also consider updating JDK. It seems you are using a pretty old OpenJDK build.